# 3D Flip Animation for View Controllers in swift

Tags: ios, git, animation, swift2, viewcontroller

I am trying to get 3d flip animations among view controllers like this

```
    https://github.com/nicklockwood/CubeController
```

For the animation.. basing on reverse value I set clock wise direction or anti clock direction

This is the code I am using for animation..

```
    class CusNavAnimController : NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

var reverse: Bool = false

func transitionDuration(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> NSTimeInterval {

    return 0.25
}

func animateTransition(transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView()

    let toViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey)!

    let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)!

    let toView = toViewController.view

    let fromView = fromViewController.view

    //
    toView.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    fromView.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds

    let direction: CGFloat = reverse ? -1 : 1
    let const: CGFloat = -0.005

    toView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(direction == 1 ? 0 : 1, 0.5)
    fromView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(direction == 1 ? 1 : 0, 0.5)

    var viewFromTransform: CATransform3D = CATransform3DMakeRotation(direction * CGFloat(M_PI_2), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    var viewToTransform: CATransform3D = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-direction * CGFloat(M_PI_2), 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)

    viewFromTransform.m34 = const
    viewToTransform.m34 = const

    containerView!.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(direction * containerView!.frame.size.width / 2.0, 0)
    toView.layer.transform = viewToTransform

    containerView!.addSubview(toView)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(transitionDuration(transitionContext), animations: {

        containerView!.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-direction * containerView!.frame.size.width / 2.0, 0)
        fromView.layer.transform = viewFromTransform
        toView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity

        }, completion: {

            finished in

            containerView!.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            fromView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
            toView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
            fromView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)
            toView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)

            if (transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled()) {

                toView.removeFromSuperview()

            } else {

                fromView.removeFromSuperview()
            }

            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled())
    })
}}
```

I am getting the animation but It is not same as the git hub link providing..
For my code.. the fromview is slightly going back and toview coming to front from that point.. can anyone suggest me the changes

Answer (score 1):

Check out `TransitionFlipFromLeft` and `TransitionFlipFromRight` in [UIViewAnimationOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions)

Comment: Will I get 3d effect for view controllers transitions by using TransitionFlipFromLeft, TransitionFlipFromRight.. Can you tell me where to add that..??

Comment: You use it to flip a view, not a view controller.  Do the following where you want the animation to happen: `[UIView transitionFromView:firstView toView:secondView duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft completion:nil]`

Comment: It will flip but while flipping it should be in 3d manner how can i set that The out put should be like this https://github.com/nicklockwood/CubeController

Comment: There's nothing like that out-of-the-box.  You'll either have to roll your own or use that CubeController class.